# Verify if text is mocked using java

Tags: java, string, selenium-webdriver, internationalization

I have a list of text that are read from an web page using `.getText()` in `selenium-webdriver`.

Now these text are in mock **eg: à_Test_海**.

I want to verify if the text has `“à”` at the beginning and `“海”` at the end of the text using `Java`.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` as below :-

```
String str = "à_Test_海";

if(str.startsWith("à") && str.endsWith("海")) 
{
// do your stuff 
}
```

Or using `charAt()` as below :-

```
if(str.charAt(0) == 'à' && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == '海') 
{
// do your stuff 
}
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Don't use charAt. It will work in this case, but if the character is changed to something above FFFF (for instance an emoji :-), this will fail. Stay with endsWith()

Answer (score 1):

if you have some string like

```
 String str = "à_ANY_STRING_HERE_海"
```

use `if( str.startsWith("à") && str.endsWith("海") )` to check begining and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with regular expressions. 
The regex would look like this: `^à.*海$`

So in java if your string is `String s = " à_Test_海";`

```
if(s.matches("^à.*海$"))
{
// this is a mock
}
else
{
// this is not a mock
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract via index and use .equals(String) but if you are doing pattern matching maybe a Pattern would be a better fit.
Something along the lines of:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("à.*海");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
boolean b = m.matches();
```